# Debugging TS in VSCode with Node: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up a new Typescript project running in Node 16 in VSCode. I'm trying to get the debugger to work.

I'm getting this error when pressing F5:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

When I set type to Module in package.json I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for c:\Users\peterB\repositories\BlockTanks\blocktanks-bots\src\main.ts
```

My setup:

- I run my code in Node 16.13.2
- I build with Gulp. Build is successful and I can run my code with `node ./dist_dev/main.js` successfully.
- I want to use the VSCode debugger in 'launch mode' instead of attaching to separate processes.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "references": [
        { "path": "src" }
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

        /* Projects */
        "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
        // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
        // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
        // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
        // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
        // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "ES2021",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        // "lib": [ "ES2021" ],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
        // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
        // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
        // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
        // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
        // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
        // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
        // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */

        /* Modules */
        "module": "CommonJS",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
        // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
        "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
        // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
        // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
        // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
        // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
        // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
        // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
        // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

        /* JavaScript Support */
        // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
        // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
        // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */

        /* Emit */
        "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
        // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
        // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
        // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
        // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
        // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
        "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
        // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
        // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
        // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
        // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
        // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
        // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
        // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
        // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
        // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
        // "noEmitHelers": true,                             /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
        "noEmitOnError": true,                               /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
        // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
        // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
        // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

        /* Interop Constraints */
        // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
        // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
        // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
        // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
        // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
        // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
        // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
        // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
        // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
        "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
        "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
        // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
        // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

        /* Completeness */
        // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
        "skipLibCheck": true,                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */

        /* Output formatting */
        "noErrorTruncation": true
    }
}
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "request": "launch",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "smartStep": true,
    "runtimeVersion": "16.13.2",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist_dev/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist_prod/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
    ],
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts",
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist_dev/**/*.js"
    ],
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Having same issue, I swear VSCode's debugger breaks at least every other month

Answer (score 5):

I see you're using Gulp but I also was getting the same `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION` error using ts-node and the VSCode debugger so just want to post what worked for me.

For anyone running ts-node using ESM modules, I got the VSCode debugger to work with the below config:

```json
// launch.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "debug with ts-node",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "--loader",
                "ts-node/esm"
            ],
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts"
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext" // or ES2015, ES2020
    },
    "ts-node": {
        // Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically
        "esm": true
    }
}
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "test-ts-node-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TypeScript project with ts-node.",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./index.ts"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```